# Can't get map with Google Map API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get a simple map on my app by using Google Map API V2; I followed all the steps to do it but when I launch my app, I only get white page with a Google logo in the left bottom.

If someone can help me with this, it will be great..

**This is the XML file:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**This is the file Java:**

```
 package com.example.ismail.location_test;

 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

**And finally the Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.ismail.location_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<permission      android:name="com.example.ismail.location_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBbHBnsC_YhHKQhhsnaahYiT3GltK52It0" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Check your google API key.

Comment: i checked it , and nothing work , and i got a new key , same probleme ,always goole logo showed

Comment: Is it a for debug mode or release mode?

Comment: then must sure that while you generate a api key with cmd then you have used relase key instead of debug key

Comment: how can i notice that ? i used this command : 
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\XX\XX\XX\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: In this `cd \Documents and Settings\.android\ $ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .keystore -storepass -keypass` you need to use `androidreleasekey` instead of `androiddebugkey`

Comment: keytool error : alias < androidreleasekey > does not exist

Comment: You need to give a path of your keytool at where it is located

Comment: i know , i did it before for the androiddebugrelease , but with the androidreleasekey an error occurred !! 
i think it's not an API KEY issue because i can  get the google logo , so it looks like something wrong with the map ....

Comment: i putted a random carractere  as API Key , and i have the same result , i tought that by seeing google logo it was ok , but now im sure that i have some probleme with the Key , i'm sure  i did all the steps as telling . should i recreate another key on google developpers or what ?

Comment: it's fixed !!! you was right piyush gupta ! it's a issue with the API key !! it's not about using androidreleasekey , i know what ut want to mean by it , but in my case i didn't activate the google map api in my enabled API .
thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. The symptom you decribe point to a not valid api key or gps is turned off, or even your are running this is an emulator with no google play installed. Check what google play versions is installed and used under build.gradle. eg:

`dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`

I suggest you post your debuger log, if it is an api error it will state it there.

Comment: i got a new key from and putted it right as the description says , the issue still persist , i can see only the google logo !!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 3 things wrong in your code :

(1) Declare permission before using it :

```
    <permission android:name="com.example.ismail.location_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <!-- after declare use this -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ismail.location_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

(2) Missing Declare gms version variable :

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

(3) Missing declare API_KEY :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaS33yBBDxSDFsdf33BK-7HCasdfSADFfa72wJnKLZvq6A" />
```

Please check with above 3 suspects first :  then if still error is there you can re-confirm steps to enable Google Maps from [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)

Comment: it's fixed !!! you was right ! it's a issue with the API key !! it's not about using androidreleasekey , i know what ut want to mean by it , but in my case i didn't activate the google map api in my enabled API . thanks a lot anyway