# Google maps android showing blue screen for 5.0.2 sony z2 tablet

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-maps

Google maps showing blue screen for 5.0.2 sony z2 tablet model where as showing current location in devices

Enabled location services though in tablet device

here is the play services version using

```
 <integer name="google_play_services_version">7095000</integer>
```

Here is the source code for showing current location on maps

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    try {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        String address = getLocationName(latitude,longitude);
        if(mCurrentLocationMarker != null){
            mCurrentLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        mCurrentLocationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        Log.i(TAG, "Latitude:" + latitude + "," + "Longitude:" + longitude);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

What would be the issue for blue screen for maps in tablet?

Comment: please screen shot and more from your implementation of code

Comment: There is something wrong in `AndroidManifest.xml`.. pls refer answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29619395/1994950

Comment: Everything is there in manifest ,when i drag blue  screen down i am able to see maps with current location and my marker .but by default when we luach its showing blue screen

Answer (score 0):

Try zooming out, a blue screen could mean that you don't have a real location and your lat and lon are zero putting you in the middle of the ocean, i.e. blue screen.  I've seen some issue with Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and it getting your location immediately.  Sometimes is has to load a lot of satellite data. Also check for the system location icon (a inverted tear drop).

Comment: I have upgraded play services to latest version and now at least blue screen going after couple of seconds automatically then map appearing